# UITableview crash during pinch zooming

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, zooming, subview, ios5

iOS5: UITableview crash during pinch zooming 
Steps: 
 1. Open table 
 2. Zoom by pinch gesture 
Crash on iOS5!!! SIGABRT 
on iOS 4.x it works fine 
What may be the reason?

Signal SIGABRT after

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return tableView;
}


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 
'The view returned from viewForZoomingInScrollView: must be a subview of the scroll view.
 It can not be the scroll view itself.'
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information. (Crash log, relevant code, etc.)

Comment: No crash log. Nothing.
Only signal SIGABRT

Comment: Edit your question to add the code (make sure you format it with the `{}` button in the editor), and pinpoint where the code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed XCode 4.2, and iOS5 on my test iPad today, and I got the same problem.

I could solve the problem by observing the sample code from Apple named ScrollViewSuite. It contains an app named TapToZoom that shows the proper implementation of the pinch zooming (that works in iOS5).
Basically, I just had then to do three things:
1- define a constant at the beginning of the .m file of the view controller (just after the #import):

```
#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
```

2-Then, I added a line at the beginning of viewDidLoad (or loadView if you don't use a nib file and create your view through coding - as for the Apple example) that sets a tag on your tableView (the table embedded in the scrollView):

```
[tableView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
```

3- Then, finally, change the value returned in the viewForZoomingInScrollView, from the previous 'return tableView' to:

```
return [scrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
```

Once these three elements were in place, my zooming not only was working again, but I realize it is now much smoother than before - which means that my previous implementation was already deficient in iOS4.

I believe that if you follow these directions, you problem should be solved. Please tell me if not. 
(technically, you could set the tag of your tableView in the interface window, then get rid of steps one and two, and just give the tag number you defined in the step 3, but on the long run the code would be less readable - at least in my opinion)

Comment: I've done as you said, but still crash on iOS5.
I am also have XCode 4.2 and iOS5.

Comment: Alex, I checked today (Feb 13,2013), and realized that the problem has disappeared - I guess it is related to the update to iOS6 or 6.1. Now I don't need anymore to have this 'ZOOM_VIEW_TAG'. On your side, did you finally find a solution to your problem?

Comment: No, I've just reorganized view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually helpful.  My app that worked fine on iOS4 also started to give this error on iOS 5.  I solved the problem by adding a subview to my scrollview (in your case the tableView) and then returning that subview in the delegate.

```
dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.bounds];
[tableView addSubview:dummyView];
```

...

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return dummyView;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But my case is special, I need to zoom tableView which is scroll view also.
If embeded tableview into scroll view
and set to scroll view scale parameters then
it works fine.
But from Apple's documentation

Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Comment: Do you mean
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return dummyView;
}
in your answer?

Comment: I edited my response to make it closer to your case.  as you said, tableView is a scrollView, so I replaced the mainScrollView in my response with it.  You were also correct about the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me and the solution were simply return the self.view instead myScrollView

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        return self.view;;
 }
```

I hope this helpful.

Comment: self.view is view which should be scrolled
Get the same error if execute your code:
The view returned from viewForZoomingInScrollView: must be a subview of the scroll view. It can not be the scroll view itself.